# PyQt assigning button commands using multiple classes

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am new to Python as well as to PyQt. I am having problems getting some of the button actions to work when I have multiple classes. For example, in my code I have the following:

```
class main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.resize(610, 570)
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("testing", 
             "testing", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

        self.stackedWidget = QtGui.QStackedWidget(Dialog)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 120, 711, 450))

        for i in range(1, 3):
            self.__dict__['page%d' % i] = QtGui.QWidget()  
            self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.__dict__['page%d' % i] )  

        self.Ui_Customer = Ui_Customer(Dialog, self.page1)
#        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Ui_Customer.pushButton_2, 
#            QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.clearalltextboxes)

#        def clearalltextboxes(self):
#            for i in range(1, 13):
#                self.Ui_Customer.__dict__['textEdit_%d' % i].clear()

        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

class Ui_Customer(main):
    def __init__(self, Dialog, page):
        for i in range(1, 3):
            self.__dict__['text_%d' % i] = QtGui.QTextEdit(page)

        self.text_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 81, 21))
        self.text_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 10, 81, 21))

        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(page)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 160, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setText("Reset")
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_2, 
            QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.clearalltextboxes)

    def clearalltextboxes(self):
        for i in range(1, 3):
            self.Ui_Customer.__dict__['textEdit_%d' % i].clear()


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    myapp = main() 
    myapp.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that when I press the "reset" button (pushbutton_2) nothing happens (I do not even get any kind of error within python). I can get it to work if I remove the commented sections out of my code. My only issue with that is that I was wanting to keep the button action command in the Ui_Customer class. Is there a way do do this?
I will eventually have several classes that the use the QtCore.QObject.connect option to assign an action to a button. I'm just having problems getting the first one to work without having to add it to the main() class.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: Never use `QObject.connect` + `QtCore.SIGNAL`. Use `my_button.clicked.connect(some_function)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the button doesn't work is because `Ui_Customer` has been made a subclass of `main` (why?) and not initialized properly. If the base class is changed to `object`, the signal handler will work - although it will generate an `AttributeError` due to a typo in the dict lookup (I think you meant `'text_%d'`).

Rather than comment on any of the individual issues with your code, I will just give one general piece of advice: create your UIs using Qt Designer and keep all your program logic in separate modules. It will make learning PyQt much easier, and is a good habit to get into for the future.